# Reuse t-sql table variable or clone its structure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, table-variable

I'm writing stored procedure to paginate results of a different stored procedure. I do it by executing the stored procedure and inserting results into the table variable:

```sql
DECLARE @allResults table
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [varchar](MAX) NULL,
    [COL1] [VARCHAR],
    [COL2] [VARCHAR],
    ...
);

INSERT @allResults Exec [dbo].[GetResults];
```

I need to filter the results and store them somewhere because I will use filtered results in at least two places: to count all the records and to actually paginate. Ideally I'd like to reuse the @allResults table as I won't need its content anymore after filtering. Something similar to:

```sql
@allresults = @allresults where [DESCRIPTION] like '%keyword%'
```

I'm not exactly sure how can I truncate table in the same moment as I filter it. That's why I created second table variable with the same structure:

```sql
DECLARE @filteredResults table
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [varchar](MAX) NULL,
    [COL1] [VARCHAR],
    [COL2] [VARCHAR],
    ...
);
```

It's not a bad solution, and it works. But I wonder could I reuse the definition of a table variable?  Something that would look like:

```sql
DECLARE @filteredResults, @allResults table
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [varchar](MAX) NULL,
    [COL1] [VARCHAR],
    [COL2] [VARCHAR],
    ...
);
```

Is there a way to do it? Maybe there's a way to clone table variable? I guess simultaneous delete and filtering could be achieved using delete with output clause but I'm not exactly sure how should I write it.

I hate to repeat code. Maybe there's a simple solution you know of :)

Comment: Could you invert the filter clause? `delete from @allresults where [DESCRIPTION] NOT like '%keyword%'`? Also CTE+ROW_NUMBER in 2k8 allow for more efficient approaches to pagination

Comment: Inverting the filter clause is possible. Not sure about performance of doing so. With this solution I wouldn't need the second variable at all. It does help avoid the problem. After filtering I do in fact use ROW_NUMBER for pagination, but I do it using subquery (as I find CTE scary and hard to understand ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own user table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo._t_test AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION] [varchar](MAX) NULL,
    [COL1] [VARCHAR],
    [COL2] [VARCHAR]
)
GO
```

And then create table variables like this:

```
DECLARE @filteredResults dbo._t_test
    , @allResults dbo._t_test
```

Comment: That would help with repetition. After creation does this type belong to the database it was created on or is it shared among databases?

Comment: From MSDN: _Creates an alias data type or a user-defined type in the current database._